# jasper table first row not displayed in pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

**First data of the java list is not displayed in Jasper report when trying to generate pdf in java.**

MY JRXML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4d180a2f-d30e-4c01-be4d-34208d1ab63f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="dataset" uuid="5c388144-2819-47f9-b534-f7f6ba299c89">
        <field name="patient_pid" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="time" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="dov" class="java.lang.String"/>

    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Image" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="clinic_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="64" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="450" y="-1" width="100" height="24" uuid="4d7ac980-0ba0-4efe-9081-1434c588323b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="0" width="50" height="22" uuid="5c4e36e4-9f79-471f-a5c5-33cae773d289"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DATE :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="50" width="595" height="1" uuid="0447b856-de6a-4e34-9fbb-3154c2cde3c5"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="180" y="10" width="200" height="30" uuid="2e998ea5-70a4-46a0-a627-b655546dd800"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{clinic_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image >
                <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="40" height="40" uuid="e8b39492-2f94-4e0c-a970-3aafa03a3dc9"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{Image}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="199" y="0" width="164" height="30" uuid="cb55a61e-a4a4-40f5-a1de-e82e038ed4a1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Doctor Appointment]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="83" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="3" y="11" width="550" height="60" uuid="c70d91e4-ae4e-44d3-926c-6a6627a502a7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset" uuid="75bd3e83-975c-4719-b1de-d6f6f66d0256">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="140" uuid="1c8bb7c9-c387-4905-95c0-e4afe5421355">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="17b976bd-3434-4ab2-be8c-8d26c89c6f9b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Patient ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="96797125-43b3-4736-8ceb-1eb465f312ba"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{patient_pid}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="170" uuid="cc0ebf66-9463-490a-815c-016fc08a7a9a">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="491a3bcd-0c94-4c94-a3be-3ffd3dc77e2d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Patient Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="437e030e-9494-4cca-9c18-5acdd62b13c9"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="67912108-963e-4d15-88a1-ff5a586e1e9f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="4e55d83d-7b00-43fe-8c9c-3e683f4ae4c2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Appointment Time]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="aa74391c-3274-49e3-9582-236d973dcc0a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="fd70d834-7bfe-49cf-8757-ffd91af0c4e2">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="ead684cb-872c-424c-aa55-d4e5f4e3da57"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Visit Date]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="b923d0bf-2df9-442a-94bc-011413c4e7f1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dov}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>

        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="73" splitType="Stretch"/>

    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This is my java controller code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = ClinicRestURIConstants.APPOINTMENTREPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public byte[] appointmentReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable Integer clinic_id,@PathVariable Integer branch_id,@PathVariable Integer doctor_id)
           throws JRException,IOException,DocumentException,SAXException {

       List<Appointment> appointmentList;
       appointmentList = appointmentreportservice.appReport(clinic_id,branch_id,doctor_id);

       String reportLocation ="E:\\ClinicManagementNew\\Clinic\\src\\main\\webapp\\static\\jrxml\\appointmentReport.jrxml";

       JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportLocation);

       File image = new File("E:\\ClinicManagementNew\\Clinic\\src\\main\\webapp\\static\\img\\logo.png");
       FileInputStream path = new FileInputStream(image);

       HashMap map = new HashMap();
       map.put("Image",path);

       if (jasperReport != null) {

           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(appointmentList));
           response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename = Report.pdf");
           OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

           JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
           exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
           exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
           exporter.exportReport();
       }
       return null;
   }
```

This java list returns two rows but only one row is displayed in the pdf.How to display the first row in that pdf.

Please, anyone, help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper studio

- Create a parameter called "MyDS" of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource. 
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd0f8.png)
- And in the table dataset select "Don't use any connection or Data Source" and select the previous "MyDS" as a REPORT_DATAS_OURCE. 
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEWPK.png)

And in your java code add your list "appointmentList" as a parameter.

```
map.put("MyDS",appointmentList);
```